# Как перенаправлять весь трафик по всем портам на другой сервер?

Tags: linux, сеть, ssh, proxy, vpn

Как перенаправлять весь трафик по всем портам на другой сервер? И также возвращать? То бишь просто объединить 2 сервера на 1 айпи. Сделать один front-end сервер, а остальной сервер что-то вроде "задней части". Приложение не веб, работает на различных портах.

Comment: А как вы на front собираетесь отличать какому серверу направлять пакет ?

Comment: 2 сервера, 2 публичных айпи. Их нужно связать и обращаться к одному, чтобы трафик потом шёл на скрытый второй.

Comment: хм. теперь еще не понятнее. у вас есть 2 сервера в интернете, с реальными ip. при приходе трафика на первый сервер вы хотите весь трафик отдать на второй ? А какую роль тогда будет выполнять первый ? И кстати, сервера находятся в одной подсети ?

Comment: @Mike видимо нужно создать "приватную сеть", объединить как-то сервера в виртуальную сеть, и делать прослушивание порта и уже внутри сети пускать трафик с одного сервера на другой. нет, не в одной подсети. Просто 2 сервера разнесенных по странам. Но нужно чтобы айпишник только 1 "светился" в интернете.

Comment: Т.е. первый сервер фактически будет только в роли маршрутизатора, т.е. сам обрабатывать как либо (кроме перенапрявления) трафик не будет ? Тогда думаю проще всего создать ip-ip туннель (см. `ip tunl`) и делать `iptables ...  -j DNAT --to-destination внутренний-ip-на-том-конце-туннеля`. На втором сервере, обратный трафик придется возвращать первому. для этого надо создать дефолтный маршрут в другой таблице маршрутизации (например таблица номер 2) `ip route add default tab 2 via внутренний-ip-на-туннеле-машины1` и завернуть в нее нужный трафик `ip rule add from ip-на-туннеле lookup 2`

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/714676/454489 только там первое правило идентично второму и смысла его дублировать я не вижу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Там предлагают делать маскарад проходящих пакетов. В этом случае вторая машина не узнает реальный ip отправителя. Критично ли это для ТС не знаю. Исхожу из худшего сценария, что ip надо сохранить

Comment: @Mike да, правильно вы поняли, никакой обработки, только маршрутизация и скрытия реального айпи сервера-приложения. А этот тунель сможешь обрабатывать трафик так же как и при прямом обращении на сервер? А про возвращение трафика на первый сервер там тоже в iptables правила нужны? Было бы хорошо статью написать на эту тему, думаю спрос был бы высокий. Если кто напишет - скиньте сюда пожалуйста. При такой реализации бэк-енд сервера можно будет менять без проблем. И запросы всегда на 1 IP будут ссылаться. нет, айпи отправителя не нужен.

Comment: Да, трафик с туннеля будет обрабатываться как обычно, туннель выглядит для системы как вторая сетевуха. У ipip туннеля может возникать проблема с MTU, т.е. с максимальным размером пакета. Потому что заголовок ipip занимает место и дописывается к пришедшему кадру. для tcp стоит на первом сервере уменьшать mss. `iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1440` (1440 для ethernet сетей). Для больших udp пакетов возможны проблемы ...

Comment: И да, если ip отправителя не нужен, то инфы по ссылке от @alexanderbarakin должно быть достаточно. отправляете пакеты без всяких туннелей на второй сервер, адрес отправителя при этом ставите свой (что и делает MASQUERADE), следовательно пакет вторая машина вернет вам. Обратные действия с ip-адресами произойдут автоматически. Не забудьте разрешить ip_forward через машину (net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 в /etc/sysctl.conf)

Comment: @Mike, если адрес отправителя не подменять, то вторая машина попытается ответить отправителю, а не первой машине. с соответствующими печальным последствиями (отправитель отбросит такие пакета как мусор).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Это если не делать туннель и не заворачивать обратный трафик насильно в него на второй машине, через отдельную таблицу маршрутизации

Comment: Может `HAProxy`?

Answer (score 1):

Можно в nginx проксировать:

```
server {
    listen 3333;

    location / {
        #ip другой машины в той же приватной сети
        proxy_pass  http://10.1.1.2:3333/;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

Или с помощью [iptables редиректить сразу](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/).

Comment: то есть любое приложение запущенное на 3333 порту будет адекватно работать на другом сервере? допустим это MySQL сервер. Это сработает?)
iptables пробовал, tcp пакеты же обратно возвращаются в теории при указывании таких правил?

Comment: @neatek должно. Но там немного по-другому https://www.nginx.com/blog/tcp-load-balancing-udp-load-balancing-nginx-tips-tricks/#TCPLB

Comment: интересно...) а "приватную сеть" между серверами не подскажете чем реализовать?

Comment: @neatek когда машины поднимаете, то выбирайте одну приватную сеть.

Comment: @neatek а есть вариант объединить 2 сервера в интернете (в разных странах) в одну виртуальную(приватную) сеть?

Comment: @neatek толку 0. Пинг большой будет, нормально работать ничего не будет.

Comment: по сути я могу поднять VPN и пустить через порт трафик через Proxy на виртуальный айпишник в сети. Точно.. а если разница в расположении между серверами будет в пару километров допустим Питер и Москва то должно быть нормально.

Comment: @neatek результаты есть? )